# rails has_many through cannot create object association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :roles_user_attributes

  has_many :roles_users
  has_many :roles, through: :roles_users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles_users, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :user_id

  has_many :roles_users
  has_many :users, through: :roles_users
end

class RolesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :role_id, :user_id, :role_attributes

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :role, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

When I run:

```
my_role = Role.find(1)
user = User.find(1)
user.roles_users.create(active: 1, role: my_role)
```

I got error `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: role`.

When I run `user.roles_users.create(active: 1, role_id: 1)` instead, it works.

I tried to change roles_user_attributes & role_attributes to roles_users_attributes & roles_attributes, but it didn't solve the problem.

I read a lot of questions on this topic, but no solution worked for me.
Don't you know why? Yet I'm quite confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here isn't really a job for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` - search "nested forms" for the kinds of things that it's used for. You should just be able to do `user.roles << my_role` without worrying about any of this stuff.

EDIT: If this isn't an option then just adding `attr_accessible :role` should do it.

Comment: even if I need attribute in join table to be saved? like the active attribute mentioned in the example.. thx

Comment: What does the active attribute do? If it's meant to signify a single role that has a special status then I would consider adding in an extra column on the user model for `active_role_id` and have `user belongs_to active_role`

Comment: `active` is kind of attribute that have to be placed in join table in DB (not in users or roles table), there can be many 'active' roles for each user

Comment: Fair enough - in that case if you change `attr_accessible :role_id` to `attr_accessible :role` then you should be good to go. If you need to mass-assign both `role` and `role_id` at difference times then you can use `attr_accessible :role, :role_id`

Comment: yes Rob, changing `attr_accessible :role_id` to `attr_accessible :role` in RolesUser solved that. now I see it is pretty obvious. thanks a lot!